# How to find gradient in other coordinate systems?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I forgot the following thing and I don't seem to find it anywhere on the internet

Let $u=f(x,y)$ and $v=g(x,y)$.

What is the gradient of $F(u,v)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Differentiation

Comment: I don't understand what that is I remember it was something simple like jacobian times something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule:

$$
\nabla F = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}F(u,v) \\
 \frac{\partial }{\partial y} F(u,v) 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}   \\
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}   \\
 \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
=  
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} \nabla u + \frac{\partial F}{\partial v} \nabla v.
$$